# Load Consecutive Pages Automatically

Tags: jquery, onload, pageload

I have created a site that generates a new version of a page every time a user makes an edit (example: site.php/?version=1, site.php/?version=2, etc). This version number and the edits are stored in a database.

I would like to make it so that loading the site index triggers the the page versions to load in consecutive order every lets say 5 seconds (version1 then version2 then version3, etc) in the same window.

Is there away to do this or something similar using jQuery (or something else)? I'm thinking that I can somehow pass the database version number into a page load function as a variable, but I'm not sure how.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want site.php to reload every 5 seconds and add 1 to whatever is the url for 'version' you could just use the following javascript (this is assuming that the user's edits are saved in sync) :

```
function getVar(name){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );

    if( results == null ){
        return "";
    }else {
        return results[1];
  }
}

var version = getVar('vesion');
version = Number(version) + 1;
window.setTimeout('window.location="http://test.com/site.php?version=' + version +'";' ,5000);
```

You may want to check that the version exists every 5 seconds instead. You would need to query the database from site.php for the current database version number and use:

```
<?php 
//query your database
?>

window.setTimeout('window.location="http://test.com/site.php?version=<?php echo $row['db_version_number']; ?>";' ,5000);
```

this will reload the database and refresh the page with whatever version is in db_version_number data cell every 5 seconds

### Edited to answer second question

to start at 10 an stop at 20:
initial url for the window would be site.php?version=10

then:

```
function getVar(name){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );

    if( results == null ){
        return "";
    }else {
        return results[1];
  }
}

var version = getVar('vesion');
version = Number(version) + 1;
if (version < 20){
    window.setTimeout('window.location="http://test.com/site.php?version=' + version +'";' ,5000);
 }
```

should do the trick

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! THANK YOU. The first function is perfect because I only want to display the existing edits. Is it possible to start and stop the reload within a specific range? (for example, start at version 10 and go to version 20?)